# WSO2 Api Manager: How to log the services

Tags: api, logging, wso2

How can I view (in carbon console or in a File) the services that are consumed by subcribers? Do I need to set a log-level? Can I see the total amount of services consumed per service of a period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Carbon Console you could set Enable Message Tracing. If you enable message tracing AND Enable logging, the carbon.log file is filled with messages;

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-04-18 13:32:48,026]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bam.message.tracer.handler.util.HandlerUtils} -  
Massage Info: Transaction id=62078996748661323020575  Message direction=IN  Server name=nxt-fon-app01.nl.rsg  Timestamp=1397820768026  
Service name=__SynapseService  Operation Name=mediate {org.wso2.carbon.bam.message.tracer.handler.util.HandlerUtils} 
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-04-18 13:32:48,046]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bam.message.tracer.handler.util.HandlerUtils} -  
Massage Info: Transaction id=62078996748661323020575  Message direction=OUT  Server name=nxt-fon-app01.nl.rsg  Timestamp=1397820768046  
Service name=__SynapseService  Operation Name=mediate {org.wso2.carbon.bam.message.tracer.handler.util.HandlerUtils}
```

This information is limited you see in incoming call and outgoing call event, but you do not see which service.

[image: WSO2 API Message Tracing]

To enable runtime statistics you should enable [BAM with API](https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics)