# How to enable application logs in wso2?

Tags: logging, log4j2, slf4j, wso2

How can I enable my application logs (API published in WSO2) in APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/log4j2.properties file? I went through the 3.0.0 documentation (https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/Administer/ProductAdministration/Monitoring/Logging/setting-up-logging/#setting-up-logging-in-api-manager) and tried to configure logging for my app component, but I'm unable to see the application specific logs in wso2carbon.log.

By using custom mediators I am able to log the complete request/response but I am looking to log all the "log.xxx()" lines I have in my code, based on the log level I set in the log4j2.properties file in WSO2. I use slf4j logger in code so I tried enabling logging for "org.slf4j" package and also tried enabling for my application's specific package, but neither worked (the "applogger" below was added to list of comma separated loggers in the same file:

```
# application logs
logger.applogger.name = org.slf4j
logger.applogger.level = DEBUG

logger.applogger.name = my.application.package
logger.applogger.level = DEBUG
```

I also checked these ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47328500/custom-application-logs-in-wso2-api-manager), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47640420/where-to-check-custom-webapplication-logs-in-wso2-carbon)) logging related questions on SO but couldn't find a definitive answer that solved my problem. When I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111647/wso2-api-manager-how-to-log-the-services/23153302#23153302) link to enable message tracing from carbon console I get the below error:

```
error
Cannot set eventing configuration. Backend server may be unavailable.; nested exception is:
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: unknown - An error has occurred. Please refer the logs for more details.
```

in logs:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-02-11 04:56:48,913] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver} - Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method configureEventing java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.message.tracer.handler.conf.RegistryPersistenceManager.updateConfigurationProperty(RegistryPersistenceManager.java:84)
.............................
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-02-11 04:56:48,922] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.message.tracer.handler.ui.MessageTracerHandlerAdminClient} - Cannot set eventing configuration. Backend server may be unavailable. org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: unknown
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
```

Comment: What is the log4j version used in your custom mediator?

Comment: I did not specify a log4j version in my custom mediator. only this was added to the sequence:
`<log level="full"> <property name="OUT_MESSAGE" value="OUT_MESSAGE"/> </log>`
I only added this temporarily in custom mediator to test if I could log the entire response. As a permanent measure, following the documentation, I am looking to add logging via the log4j2.properties file.

Comment: Sorry. I thought that you are using a custom class mediator. So your requirement is to log the request and response and achieved it via adding custom mediators. Can you explain the application you are talking about? I'm not quite clear on what you are trying with log4j2.properties?

Comment: **Application**: My Backend API that I have published in WSO2 API-M.

**Requirement**: I have log.info(), log.debug() statements in my API code which I would like to see printed in some logs (ex: wso2carbon.log) and I am unable to get that. This is where log4j2.properties comes in.

I just mentioned as a side note that complete request/response logging is happening via custom mediators, but this is separate from my actual requirement of logging INFO/DEBUG/ALL statements within my code. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> By using custom mediators I am able to log the complete
> request/response but I am looking to log all the "log.xxx()" lines I
> have in my code, based on the log level I set in the log4j2.properties
> file in WSO2. I use slf4j logger in code so I tried enabling logging
> for "org.slf4j" package and also tried enabling for my application's
> specific package, but neither worked (the "applogger" below was added
> to list of comma separated loggers in the same file:
>
> logger.applogger.name = org.slf4j
>
> logger.applogger.level = DEBUG
>
> logger.applogger.name = my.application.package
>
> logger.applogger.level = DEBUG

Seems like you have added same name repetitively. Add following your application logger as follows:

```
logger.applogger.name = my.application.package 
logger.applogger.level = DEBUG
```

and set it to the loggers configuration:

```
loggers = AUDIT_LOG, trace-messages, org-apache-coyote, com-hazelcast, Owasp-CsrfGuard, org-apache-axis2-wsdl-codegen-writer-PrettyPrinter.... org-wso2-carbon-apimgt-gateway-mediators-BotDetectionMediator,correlation, JAGGERY_LOG, applogger
```

You do not need to set the logger name as `org.slf4j`. You should only specify the package name the component. Check whether the back-end implementation is using log4J2 for logging. If not, there might be issues due to dependency version mismtach.

Comment: I did not add the applogger name repetitively. They were both added separately to try both ways to see if anything worked (_I use slf4j logger in code so I tried enabling logging for "org.slf4j" package and also tried enabling for my application's specific package, but neither worked_). If my backend implementation doesn't use log4j2, what can I do to get logs?

Comment: Since we are not using log4j2 in our backend implementation what can be done to generate log statements in wso2 logs?